# Which software to batch join videos and add a chapter for each?

Tags: video, mac

I have 55 short clips (<1min) that have the same characteristics (only the content and length change) and I want to combine them into one big chaptered video.
I know with QTPro how to combine 2 videos and how to add chapters to 1 file. 
Now I need a Mac OS X tool that's gonna do it automagically.

*P.S. I ask here cause I know many Mac users are video professionals, if it doesnt't fit though I'll ask on apple.stackexchange.*

Comment: This is a near duplicate of [Concatenating videos (mp4) in Mac](http://superuser.com/questions/51047/concatenating-videos-mp4-in-mac)

Comment: @ObscureRobot I think it's okay that it's on both sites. There's a "assembling your own videos" context here that I think is useful, plus that other question wouldn't come up in a search on this site. However, linking it as you have is very useful, since I suspect one of its answers is valid here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ever since the fall of Visual Hub, there have been several generations of programs that have taken up the sourcecode and tried to remake the magic.  Visual Hub was awesome at stitching files together, sad it no longer works.  Film Redux was a fork of VisualHub, but has since been abandoned also. You can still [download FilmRedux for free](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/31954/filmredux), however I can't get it to process any of my files. It may just be a configuration issue on my machine, you may have better luck.

Your Mac should have come with iMovie, otherwise it's at the [Mac App Store for $15](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imovie/id408981434?mt=12).  I found [this comprehensive guide to iMove '09](http://www.kenstone.net/fcp_homepage/imovie_09_stone.html#markers) and the section on markers is still relevant to iMovie '11.  The drawback is you'll have to add them manually, but that shouldn't be *too* much trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create such chaptered file just draggin all your small files into  [SimpleMovieX](http://simplemoviex.com/SimpleMovieX/new.html).

(As crew of Aero Quartet I may receive some form of compensation, financial or otherwise, from my recommendation or link.)

Comment: It is customary to add a note indicating your affiliation with the recommended software.

Comment: My fault George. As crew of Aero Quartet I may receive some form of compensation, financial or otherwise, from my recommendation or link.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I'll add that to your answer.  (By the way, it does look pretty easy to do what the OP is asking for in that software.)